# Is Cast to void** needed?

Tags: c

I have the compiler complaining (warning) about the folowing.

Am I missing something? Because I thought this didn't need a cast

```
char* CurrentCh  = some ptr value;
int size;

size = func(&CurrentCh);
```

with func defined like this

```
int func(void** ptr);
```

Compiler warning:

> passing argument 1 of 'func'
>   from incompatible pointer type

Thx

Comment: Any particular reason you can't just have `func(void * ptr);` and pass like `func(CurrentCh);`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C you can pass any pointer type to a function that expects a void*. What it says is "I need a pointer to something, it doesn't matter what it points to". Whereas void** says "I need a pointer to a void*, not a pointer to another pointer type".

Comment: Correct, your function declaration is asking specifically for a 'pointer to void', not for 'pointer to pointer to void'. If you change that to func(void* ptr) it should work correctly. I do have to wonder why you want a pointer to a pointer, unless it's an array of pointers.

Comment: Because I want ptr to be a "return parameter": I expect CurrentCh to point to something else after the call. I am doing it wrong.
(note that my real function already has a return parameter).

Comment: then you need just one pointer, and will have to cast it to the desired type too.

Answer (score 4):

In C, `void *` is the generic pointer type.  But `void **` is not a generic pointer-to-pointer type!  If you want to be able to pass a pointer to a pointer in a generic way, you should use `void *` anyway:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(void *ptr)
{
    char **actual = ptr;
    const char *data = *actual;
    printf("%s\n", data);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *test = "Hello, world";
    func(&test);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ok but but then it is not clear in the "func" definition that is assuming ptr to be a return parameter, isn't it?

Comment: @matkas: Yes, you have a choice of either doing what I did, or declaring `func()` as `func(char **ptr)`.

Answer (score 3):

The cast is necessary as what you do is a form of type punning: You reinterpret the memory which is pointed to from `char *` to `void *`.

For these types, the C standard guarantees that this actually works as `char *` and `void *` have the same representation. For other type combinations, this may not be the case.

The relevant parts of the standard are section 6.2.5, §27

> A pointer to void shall have the same
>   representation and alignment
>   requirements as a pointer to a
>   character type. Similarly, pointers
>   to qualified or unqualified versions
>   of compatible types shall have the
>   same representation and alignment
>   requirements. All pointers to
>   structure types shall have the same
>   representation and alignment
>   requirements as each other. All
>   pointers to union types shall have the
>   same representation and alignment
>   requirements as each other. Pointers
>   to other types need not have the same
>   representation or alignment
>   requirements.

and less relevant (but perhaps also interesting) section 6.3.2.3, §7

> A pointer to an object or incomplete
>   type may be converted to a pointer to
>   a different object or incomplete type.
>   If the resulting pointer is not
>   correctly aligned for the pointed-to
>   type, the behavior is undefined.
>   Otherwise, when converted back again,
>   the result shall compare equal to the
>   original pointer. When a pointer to an
>   object is converted to a pointer to a
>   character type, the result points to
>   the lowest addressed byte of the
>   object. Successive increments of the
>   result, up to the size of the object,
>   yield pointers to the remaining bytes
>   of the object.

Anything beyond that is implementation-specific.

Answer (score 0):

In C, any pointer can downcast to void*, but not to void**.  You will need an explicit cast.